# What should I say when someone is in the following position?

Tags: word-usage, meaning, meaning-in-context, word-choice, idioms

To describe this image can I say, "He sticks his feet to the windshield. "?

What should I say when someone is in the following position?

[image: lrs;0;[1]lrs;0;[1]]

Comment: I have commented on the same question on ELU.

Comment: You should say "Put your goddam feet down!! Were you raised in a barn?"

Answer (score 1):

His shoes are on the windshield. (Or the bottom/soles of his shoes.)

His shoes/feet are pressing against the windshield.

He's got his shoes up against the windshield.

He's putting/resting his legs on the dashboard.

"Sticking" doesn't work very well because it suggests that it's somehow adhesive.